# Style Auth0's universal login header for small screen sizes?

Tags: auth0

Is it possible the style the header of the universal login page with Auth0?

On mobile I'm seeing a salmon pink color

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the "Hosted Pages" menu link at manage.auth0.com you can customise the HTML of the page. I've written some CSS in a style tag in the document head but you could also also link to an external stylesheet.